# Поиск и замена значения в списке (list)

Tags: python

Как поменять значение `13` на `3` в `а=[«вв», 13, «цн»]` Не меняя другие значения и не зная на каком месте стоит 13. (Не используя следующую запись `а[1]`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Второй вариант найти индекс для `13` и заменить на `3`

```py
a=["вв", 13, "цн"]
a[a.index(13)] = 3
print(a)

# OUT
# ['вв', 3, 'цн']
```

Comment: Но будет проблема, если таких элементов несколько )  Поменяется только первый

Comment: Абсолютно, но этого нет в условии, что список хранит несколько значений и надо заменить все)

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет **списковое сокращение** и **тернарный оператор**:

```
a = [3 if x == 13 else x for x in a]
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- тернарный оператор
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- списковое сокращение
```

Если создавать новый список нельзя, а нужно обязательно менять старый список, то просто перебираете его индексы и элементы и заменяете подходящий элемент:

```
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    if x == 13:
        a[i] = 3
```